# Azure pipeline . Install sudo in ubuntu 18.04 docker container failed - Permission Denied

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-pipelines, ubuntu-18.04, sudo

I am trying to run CI/CD in Azure pipeline .Because my app need some dependencies that only work ubuntu 18.04 however that VmImage version deprecated in Azure hosted agent. That is why I run it on ubuntu 18.04 docker container. It seem the docker container does not have sudo installed so I try to install it. Here is my pipeline code

```
  pool: 
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  container: ubuntu:18.04
  dependsOn: ImpactedProjects
  condition: eq(dependencies.ImpactedProjects.outputs['ImpactAnalysis.Project.Loyalty.QueryCachePopulator.AzureFunction.BddTests'], 'True')
  steps:
  - script: apt-get install sudo
    displayName: 'Install sudo'
```

However then I got this error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
##[error]Bash exited with code '100'.
Finishing: Install sudo
```

Is there anyone know how to fix this please. Thanks

Comment: There aren't really any use cases that require `sudo` in a container.  When you launch a container, you can usually specify what user it runs as, which can be root; once the container is running, it only has a single process and won't usually be switching users.  You talk about your app needing dependencies installed; would it work to `RUN apt-get ...` in your image's Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze . I try to run some script command for example I try to install libicu60 with this script task

  - script: |
      apt-get update
      apt-get install -y libicu60
    displayName: 'Install libicu'

And I got permission denied error. That is werid though. I expect Microsoft should auto give me root user permission if they allow me to run the pipeline in docker container.

Comment: What is in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @JNguyen Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT . Thank. Where did you put your Dockerfile ? In the example code I don't see where do you specify the file path to it ?

Comment: @JNguyen You need to use another pipeline to create and push the docker image to docker hub or ACR or some other private docker register first. Then you can use your custom docker image in container job. Or you can create and push the image on your local machine

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT  seem it does not work. I can see in the pipeline logs when it initialise the container step something like this :

"
Try to create a user with UID '1001' inside the container.

Grant user 'vsts_azpcontainer' SUDO privilege and allow it run any command without authentication.

Allow user 'vsts_azpcontainer' run any docker command without SUDO."

It happen in both cases when I used default ubuntu 18.04 or our custom image. It seem that the image already give us root user but Azure pipeline somehow revoke it.

Comment: If  you can reproduce the issue. I think you can see those logs as well. It is in "Initialize containers" step

Comment: @JNguyen Please refer to my update part  in the answer and check if the sample can work for you when installing the sudo package

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Thank. it worked now. Would you mind to see if you can help me in another similar question please. Thanks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652492/run-dotnet-test-in-ubuntu-18-04-docker-container-azure-pipeline-however-the-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the ubuntu 18.04 in Container job.

[image]

The cause of this issue is that this image runs as non-root, so for root-access things you have to switch into root.

In a Dockerfile, you can simply switch user identities with a USER directive; this generally defaults to running as root:

```
USER root
```

To resolve this issue, you need to custom your docker image based on the image: `ubuntu18.04`.

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
RUN apt-get install sudo
USER 1001
```

Then you can use the custom image in container job.

For example:

```
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
container: 
 image: xxx/ubuntu18.04:23787
 endpoint: dockerserviceconnection
 options: --user root --privileged

steps:
- script: sudo apt-get install sudo
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/issues/194) and doc: [Container Job  Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#options)

**Update**

We can use the following sample to install the sudo package to the existing Ubuntu 18.04 image.

```
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

container: 
 image: ubuntu:18.04
 options: "--name sample -v /usr/bin/docker:/tmp/docker:ro"

steps:
  - script: |
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u root sample mv /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u root sample apt-get -qq update
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u root sample apt-get -qq install sudo
      /tmp/docker exec -t -u root sample mv /etc/sudoers.bak /etc/sudoers
  - script: sudo xxx
```

**Note:** If you are using the Microsoft-hosted agent, we need to use the **VMimage: ubuntu-20.04**

For more detailed info, you can refer to this ticket: [Can't acquire root on common container distros](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2043)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be the `root` user within the Docker container so you can install packages. If you're running this with a `docker run` command, try setting the following environment variables as part of your `docker run` command:

```bash
-e USERID=0 -e GROUPID=0
```

Comment: The thing is I dont do any docker run command yet. As you can see from my code. I just state the docker container version and the pipeline auto initialize the container for me .